# log4net AdoNetAppender - SqlParameterCollection does not contain parameters

Tags: c#, log4net, adonetappender

In one of my projects I get this error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: SqlParameterCollection does not contain SqlParameter with ParameterName "@log_date".
в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.GetParameter(String parameterName)
в System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Data.IDataParameterCollection.get_Item(String parameterName)
в log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter.FormatValue(IDbCommand command, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
в log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(IDbTransaction dbTran, LoggingEvent[] events)
в log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
```

Here is appender configuration (which works perfectly in others projects):

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
        <bufferSize value="1" />
        <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <connectionString value="Data Source=*****;Initial Catalog=****;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
        <commandText value="INSERT INTO [LogsDB].[dbo].[Logs] ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@log_date" />
            <dbType value="DateTime" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
        </parameter>
        .
        .
        .
        <parameter>
            <parameterName value="@exception" />
            <dbType value="String" />
            <size value="2000" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
        </parameter>
    </appender>
```

If someone had this problem, I'll really appreciate for helping

Comment: Have you just upgraded to 1.2.14 as there [seems to be an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-489)

Comment: @stuartd I just reproduced this. All other appenders seem to work.

Comment: Really... in this new project I have the latest version of log4net

Comment: will try to downgrade it and then post here the result

Comment: It looks like this has been resolved in 2.0.5.

Answer (score 12):

Install-Package Log4net -Version 2.0.3

Work for me(have same problem)

Comment: Downgrading it to [2.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/2.0.3) solved the problem for now.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorted it for me too... Thanks

Comment: No need to downgrade now - Version 2.0.5 fixes the problem, just don't use 2.0.4!!

Answer (score -1):

Solved it. Upgraded Log4Net to 2.04 ! Then ran the command supplied above !
No idea what I am doing. But I am now able to log to the database !

Comment: If you mean the command `Install-Package Log4net -Version 2.0.3` then you just downgraded to the 2.0.3 version. You can read about the bug [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-489).