# log4net [1.2.14] - Generic Failure - Parameter Missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, logging, log4net

I am getting the following error in the log4net error log:

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Exception while writing to database
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@logId' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.GetParameter(String parameterName)
   at System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection.System.Data.IDataParameterCollection.get_Item(String parameterName)
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter.FormatValue(IDbCommand command, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(IDbTransaction dbTran, LoggingEvent[] events)
   at log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.SendBuffer(LoggingEvent[] events)
```

Here is the code from the web.config:

```
<commandText value="INSERT INTO WebTeamAdminAppLog ([ID],[Date],[Application],[Server],[ProcessId],[Login],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception],[SessionId]) VALUES (@logId,@log_date,@app,@server,@processId,@login,@thread,@log_level,@logger,@message,@exception,@sessionid)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logId" />
    <dbType value="Guid" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
      <key value="logId" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
```

Not sure what the problem is since this code is from another project that inserts logs into the database just fine. It is the same database, just a different table. The version of log4net in the other application is 1.2.13.0. Also, when I step through the debugger, the logId value seems to be getting set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the following SO post. Seems to be the exact problem I am having: [log4net AdoNetAppender - SqlParameterCollection does not contain parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696604/log4net-adonetappender-sqlparametercollection-does-not-contain-parameters)

Downgrading to 1.2.13 fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Upgrading to 1.2.15 also works.  This issue is isolated to1.2.14.  Reference comment from Gonzalo Diaz above.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code if you have something like this:

```
 Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
 var loggingEvent = new LoggingEvent(.....)
 loggingEvent.Properties["logId"] = id;
```

Comment: I have something very similar to that: Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid(); log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["logId"] = guid;

Comment: Try updating to version 1.2.15. It seems to be a problem with version 1.2.14. Check: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-489?jql=text%20~%20%22An%20SqlParameter%20with%20ParameterName%20is%20not%20contained%20by%20this%20SqlParameterCollection%22